# Set user and pws in linked table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

With the below code I set the linked table parameters, I set `Usr` and `Pws` but every time that program starts and I use the linked table I received this error:

[image] 
and then 
[image]

Now I have to unflag the trusted connection and input the `Usr` and `Pws` again.

What is causing this?

```
Public Function SetLinkedTablesTruck()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf As TableDef
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler    
    Set db = CurrentDb
    ' Loop Table Defs
    For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    If tdf.Name = "TruckOUT" Then
    MsgBox tdf.Connect
    tdf.Connect = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=MYITSRV;DATABASE=dbItalianDb;TABLE=dbo.truckView;UID=UserView;PWD=UserView"
        tdf.RefreshLink
        db.TableDefs.Refresh
    End If

    Next

    Set tdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

    MsgBox "Tables Re-Linked"

ExitHandler:
   Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
   MsgBox "Error in SetLinkedTables : " & err.Description
   Resume ExitHandler

End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

You normally do not include the table name, thus:

```
tdf.Connect = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=MYITSRV;DATABASE=dbItalianDb;UID=UserView;PWD=UserView"
```

Comment: thanks but that isn't the problem, I tried without table name but the problem is the same

Comment: Then try to expand the connection string with: `Trusted_Connection=No` as it seems the server expects a trusted connection while you provide both `UID` and `PWD`.